# Xstl global variable set in for each and used after foreach

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

First of all, I'm new to XSLT.
I'm working with Sharepoint list and I need to get a link to show up if there's data in specific quarters. If there's no data in a certain quarter, I need to have a label that says so.

So what I did is that i created a foreach loop for each data of the same Month of a given year.I know that i cannot re-assing a variable in xslt but I dont know how to do what I want.
Here's a sample of my code. Since I'm working with Sharepoint i dont have acces to the XML. :/

```
<xsl:variable name="DataQ1" select="'False'"/>
<xsl:variable name="DataQ2" select="'False'"/>
<xsl:variable name="DataQ3" select="'False'"/>
<xsl:variable name="DataQ4" select="'False'"/>
<xsl:for-each select="../Row[generate-id()=generate-id(key('MonthKey', substring(@Date,6,7))[substring('@Date',1,4) = $varYear)][1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="currentMonth" select="number(substring(@Date,6,7))"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$currentMonth &gt;= 1 and $currentMonth $lt;=4">
            <!--set $DataQ1 to true-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$currentMonth &gt;= 4 and $currentMonth $lt;=7">
            <!--set $DataQ2 to true-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$currentMonth &gt;= 7 and $currentMonth $lt;=10">
            <!--set $DataQ3 to true-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!--set $DataQ4 to true-->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
<div>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$DataQ1= 'True'">
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="www.example.come"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="'LinkToDataofQ1'"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'There's no data for this quarter.'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</div>
```

Comment: Please, *edit* the question and provide the exact (preferably small) source XML document and the exact wanted result of the transformation. Also, please, explain the requirements (rules/constraints) that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `key` function in your example code but you didn't post the declaration of your key. But I think you can achieve what you want with the following code:

```
<div>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="../Row[substring(@Date, 1, 4) = $varYear and substring(@Date, 6, 2) &gt;= 1 and substring(@Date, 6, 2) &lt; 4]">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/">LinkToDataofQ1</a>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>There's no data for this quarter.</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</div>
```

Some other notes:

- In your test for Q1 you wrote `$currentMonth <= 4`. I think what you want is `$currentMonth < 4`.
- To extract the month from `@Date` you used `substring(@Date, 6, 7)`. The third argument to `substring` is the length of the substring, not the end index. So you'll probably should write `substring(@Date, 6, 2)`.
- Instead of `<xsl:value-of select="'string'"/>`, you can simply write `string`.

Comment: Thank you that's exacly what I was looking for. And sorry for my many mistakes. :/ Good to see that you could still understand what I wanted!